# Геокодер, узнать этаж и тип дома?

Tags: геокодирование

Если смотреть карту под наклоном, видны структуры зданий и высота. Похоже Яндекс знает эту информацию, но геокодер похоже не выдает.

Есть ли возможность получить такую информацию?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ни у Google, ни у Yandex сведений об этажности зданий нет. Государство не предоставляет этим сервисам информацию об этажности зданий, да и в общем-то она им ни к чему.

Есть только примерные границы "прямоугольников зданий", а так же их примерная высота.

Для большинства зданий в мире, эти сведения изначально были вычислены путем обработки спутниковых или аэроснимков, сделанных с разных ракурсов, в разное время суток(здания перекрывают друг-друга, да отбрасывают тени).

Алгоритмы далеко не совершенны, и порой получаются "ляпы", вроде "небоскрёбов стоящих посреди необитаемых скал". Поэтому сведения постоянно уточняются по отзывам пользователей(с той же "народной карты" Яндекса), а так же из показаний лазерных дальномеров установленных на машинах для съемки панорам улиц(да, там далеко не только фотокамеры).